# Get parent users child user for only level 7th

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get users of Parent from 1 to 7th level only.

Also I want to show the number of users count like on 1 level has total 15 users.

I have tired with the below recursion function but it's not working as it should be work.

[PHP How do I calculate level of nested calls in recursive function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254481/php-how-do-i-calculate-level-of-nested-calls-in-recursive-function)

Below is the users table structure:

[image]

How I can achieve result like below screenshot:

[image]

Please help me guys.

Comment: Which query have you tried so far?

Comment: @shahsani, I am unable to create the query for that. So that's why I have posted here.

Comment: @mageDev0688 Is it just one to one ?

Comment: @BasheerAhmedKharoti, yes It's just one to one, but every user has a child users and they will from 1 to 7th level only.

Comment: If a users has more then one then how could this be a one to one?

Comment: @BasheerAhmedKharoti yes you are right. User A has more than one child users and same User B has more than on child users. This is based on the referral program. So User A can refer more than one User.

Comment: This is called an "Adjacency list", which is a form of hierarchical data.  It's not my preferred method of doing it.  I prefer using the Materialized path method.

Comment: @mageDev0688 - are you willing to change the schema of your table? basically change from adjacency list to materialized path.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, Yes I can change the schema of table but I have concern how I can insert the record in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets try this again.   If it's a many to many relationship it's not tree or hierarchical data.

To put it simply, a Node with hierarchical can only have 2 connections in the "data model"  Those would be a parent and a child.

For a Many to many relationship, you could have 6 users that are related to each other, that would give you something like `6^6 or 46,656` possible combinations ( or something like that, anyway its way more then 2 ).

You mention something about levels, I still have no idea what this is.  Is this permission levels?

These levels wont necessarily work how you expect ( of course I have no idea what they are ) but just logically if you have a Many to many relationship then

```
 If user A is related to User B
 Than
 user B is equally related to User A
```

Say user `A` is level `1` and user `B` is level `2`.  Now because `A=B` then `B=A`.  Now how do you know which level to use?

Anyway a Many to Many relationship is like DB architecture 101, it's basic.  What you need is a `bridge` table ( sometimes called a `junction` table ).  So you have a `users` table then you have a `users_users` table.

[image]

Here is a image I found that shows this, using students and classes. Its the same idea here, except we can use the `users` table for both sides of the relationship.  It's common to name them `table1_table2` so we get `users_users`.  This is a nice image and show what I want, just think of a Many to Many as a Many to One and a One to Many relationship ( because that is what it is ).  This helps explain why we need the extra table and can't represent this within just one table.

Check this fiddle out before I go on with more

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6yRBW4jpBJR3MkVpUZP47f/2

This can be shown this way ( in a rudimentary way )

```
users
    id  :   name
    1   :   A
    2   :   B
    3   :   C
    4   :   D
    5   :   E
    6   :   F
    7   :   G
    8   :   H
    9   :   I

users_users ( brige table )
parent  : child
    1   :   2
    1   :   3
    1   :   4
    1   :   5

    2   :   3
    2   :   4
    2   :   5
```

So user 1 is the parent of `2,3,4,5` And user 2 is the parent of `3,4,5`.  It's important to note that a user could be both a parent and a child of another user  For example:

```
users_users ( brige table )
parent  : child
    1   :   2
    2   :   1
```

Now `1` is the parent of `2`, and `2` is the parent of `1` and vise versa.  What this means is up to how you code it and the conventions you want to impose on it.

Pay close attention to the select queries in the fiddle.  Pay attention to what side is the parent and what side is the child.

Now we can easly add another column named `level` See this fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6yRBW4jpBJR3MkVpUZP47f/4

And our updated schema

```
users
    id  :   name    :   level
    1   :   A       :       1
    2   :   B       :       2
    3   :   C       :       3
    4   :   D       :       4
    5   :   E       :       5
    6   :   F       :       6
    7   :   G       :       7
    8   :   H       :       8
    9   :   I       :       9
```

So if we wanted to find users of a given level, we would have to decide whos level to use. This is because both the parent and the child are users, and both then have a level assigned to them.

I guess we should use the parents level.  So if we wanted to find all users that have a parent of level one we would use this query.

```
    SELECT
        c.id AS child_id, c.name AS child_name, p.level AS parent_level
    FROM
        users AS p
    JOIN
        users_users AS u ON p.id = u.parent
    JOIN
        users AS c ON c.id = u.child
    WHERE
        p.level = 1;
```

This would return users `2,3,4,5` which are all children of user 1 ( which is level 1 ).  However each user themselves has a level different then `1`.  If we just wanted the users that had level 1.  We would just query the `users` table

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE level=1
```

We could also do the reverse and find all parents that have a child of a specific level.  For that we just change the columns we are looking up to be prefixed with the `p.` for parent and then we also flip the condition in the `WHERE` clause to use the child `c.`  Like this:

```
SELECT
    p.id AS parent_id, p.name AS parent_name, c.level AS child_level
FROM
    users AS p
JOIN
    users_users AS u ON p.id = u.parent
JOIN
    users AS c ON c.id = u.child
WHERE
    c.level = 2;
```

HERE I switched level to 2 ( no results for 1 ), this returns `User1`, this would be the same for child levels `2,3,4 and 5` would all return `1` for this.  Because we have this relationship

```
users_users ( brige table )
parent     : child
1  {lv 1}  :   2  {lv 2}
1  {lv 1}  :   3  {lv 3}
1  {lv 1}  :   4  {lv 4}
1  {lv 1}  :   5  {lv 5}
```

So you can see if we look up `child.level=2` we get the first relationship, and if we do the opposite `parent.level=1` we get all the relationship for that user.

This does seem to fit better to what you were saying in the comments, but I am still not sure I fully understand what you want.

One last thing that is very important, for the bridge table.  Make sure you understand the compound primary key used for this in the fiddle

```
CREATE TABLE `users_users` (
 `parent` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `child` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`parent`,`child`) #this is the compound key
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here we are combining the user id from both sides `parent/child` as the primary key.  This prevents having duplicate entries for the relationship.  So imagine the key for this as

```
users_users ( brige table )
parent  : child   : {key}
    1   :   2     : {1~2}
    1   :   3     : {1~3}

    2    :  1     : {2~1}  #<-- this is not a duplicate of {1~2}

    #1  :   2     : {1~2}  #<-- this key would be a duplicate
                           # and is not allowed, trying to add this
                           # will throw a duplicate key error from the DB
```

I almost forgot for your `status` field we can just add that into our DB schema as a simple `boolean` field.  This will be a 1 for Active and a 0 for inactive.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `level` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then we just add that to the `WHERE` clause when we need it, pretty simple you can sort that out I am sure.  `WHERE p.status=1 AND c.level = 2;`

Comment: In my case which one should I need to use? Could you please suggest me?

Comment: I would use Materialized path, as I said.

Comment: Now about your question.  You say `Parent from 1 to 7th level only`, do you mean the immediate children?  Or "nodes" that have those ids in their tree.  Take just #7, if you look #9 has #8 as its parent, and #8 has #7 as its parent, so #7 would be the "grand parent" of #l9.  In other words, #9 has #7 as part of it's tree.  So by selecting 1-7 ( if its anywhere in the tree ) that would include all your data, basically.

Comment: Also when you say, 7th level, do you actually mean the `level` column, or do you mean the parent column.

Comment: I think your idea of User Level is different then my Idea of Level.   Yours looks to be the access level of the user, not what level they are in the tree, right?

Comment: yes you are correct, I have created the referral website program. It has is a self  parent,User A has referred to User B.

So User B is on **LEVEL 1** for User A.
And same as the **User C** is on LEVEL 2 for User A.
And same as the **User D** is on LEVEL 3 for User A.
And same as the **User E** is on LEVEL 4 for User A.
And same as the **User F** is on LEVEL 5 for User A.
And same as the **User G** is on LEVEL 6 for User A.
And same as the **User H** is on LEVEL 7 for User A.

Comment: Ok, I was wrong your idea of a level is the same as mine, just I seen they were all 0's

Comment: I am show you a ruff screenshot so that you can see [here](https://cryptogain.online/usrlevel/user_levels.jpg). I have created the image for better solution. In every level has nth number of users. And every user can refer nth number of users. As well as I have to manage status **Active** and **Deactivated** users. Please help me Artistic

Comment: are you talking about a many to many relationship between users?

Comment: I don't know you are going to have to explain this better, I cant keep wasting time on this.  Anyway that looks like a big Onion or maybe magnetic fields to me...  Anyway what you are talking about above is a many to many relationship and that is vastly different then tree data.

Comment: Yes, 1 user can refer many users, and If **User A** refer to **User B** than **User B** is on **Level 1** and if **User B** refer to **User C** than **User C** will be on **Level 1** for **User B** but **User C** will be on **Level 2** for **User A**. This chain will be again and again for all users.

Comment: Yes, it's many relationship. How I can manage and insert users in the table so I can get number of users according to their level.

Comment: @mageDev0688 - let me know if that is close to what you had in mind. As you can see I do a lot of typing ... lol.  I manage a small team of developers, I am a CIO with 6+ years experience programming.  So I am used to `training` my developers these higher level concepts.

Comment: That's great Artistic, let me try once according to your suggestion. I am working on this and will update you asap.

Comment: sorry for replying delay, I think you have updated your answer and removed the **level** insert code. Could you please add here? Thanks in advance.